# SQL Loop and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
Vers | Rev
3    | A
7    | B
13   | C
```

And a second table:

```
Info | Version
aab  | 1
adr  | 2
bhj  | 3
bgt  | 4
nnh  | 4
ggt  | 7
```

I need to have a table:

```
Info | Version | Rev
aab  | 1       | A
adr  | 2       | A
bhj  | 3       | A
bgt  | 4       | B
nnh  | 4       | B
ggt  | 7       | B
```

How do I achieve the final table?
Rev A is for Versions 1-3, Rev B is versions 4-7, Rev C is versions 5-13.
If I were trying to do this with VB Excel, I would add a 1 in a new column. Then get the first Vers value (3) - second Vers value (7) then output 4....
Then I would use some logic If <= new column and >= Vers write Rev.
I don't know how to do this in SQL and I need to!

Comment: what is the logic that determines the third column in the output table?

Comment: I would suggest you to read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You should really give a bit more context.

Comment: Do you mean rev C is 8-13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `outer apply`:

```
select t2.*, t1.rev
from table2 t2 outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t2.version <= t1.vers
      order by t1.vers asc
     ) t1;
```

This gets the "next" version in `table1` relative to each version in `table2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can do it by joining tables

```
select 
t2.Info Info
,t2.Version Version
,t1.Rev Rev
from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t2.Version=t1.Vers;
```

Comment: This isn't going to work - it will only assign t1.Rev to versions 3, 7, 13... etc.

Comment: You can try this if it doesn't work 
SELECT t2.Info, t2.Version, t1.Rev
FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1
    ON (t2.Version=t1.Vers)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
, (SELECT TOP 1 b.rev 
   FROM Table1 b 
   WHERE a.version <= b.vers 
   ORDER BY b.vers)
FROM Table2 a
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a third version:

```
declare @t1 table(V int, R char(1))
insert @t1 values (3,'A'),(7,'B'),(13,'C')
declare @t2 table(I char(3), V int)
insert @t2 values ('aab',1),('adr',2),('bhj',3),('bgt',4),('nnh',4),('ggt',7)

select t2.*, t1.R 
from @t2 t2
join @t1 t1 on t1.V>=t2.V and not exists(select * from @t1 t3 where t3.V>=t2.v and t3.V<t1.V)
```